Select best predictor from multiple ROC Curves in R
Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(plotROC)
library(pROC)
library(ROCR)

3 regression models
modele1 <- glm(USI3 ~ SBEcl3 + AGE3 + SEXE3 + RL3 + ATB3 + 
    OXYGENE3 + NEW3 , data = data3, family = binomial)
modele2 <- glm(USI3 ~ LACTATES3 + AGE3 + SEXE3 + RL3 + ATB3 + 
    OXYGENE3 + NEW3 , data = data3, family = binomial)
modele3 <- glm(USI3 ~ SOFA3 + AGE3 + SEXE3 + RL3 + ATB3 + 
    OXYGENE3 + NEW3 , data = data3, family = binomial)

(data3 defined at end of post)
Prediction models
predict(modele1)
predict(modele2)
predict(modele3)

3 ROC Curves
rocs <- list()
rocs[["modele1"]] <- roc(data3$USI3, predict(modele1))
rocs[["modele2"]] <- roc(data3$USI3, predict(modele2))
rocs[["modele3"]] <- roc(data3$USI3, predict(modele3))
ggroc (rocs, legacy.axes = TRUE)

Results

I want to determine the best discriminative score (SBE3, LACT3,  SOF3) for predict risk of USI admission(USI3). I transformed these continuous variables into qualitative and incorporated them into my models. I make my prediction from my regression models, theses prediction are very poor (AUC1 = 0.74, AUC2 = 0.72, AUC3 = 0.79).
Does this method seem appropriate to you? How to have a better prediction? Do you have another method to suggest to me? How to select in advance the threshold values ​​of the different predictive factors for admission to the ICU using the ROC curve analysis?
This is my data
structure(list(USI3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("non", 
"oui"), class = "factor"), SBEcl3 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L
), levels = c("Q3", "Q1", "Q2", "Q4"), class = "factor"), VBEcl3 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Q2", "Q1", "Q3"), class = "factor"), 
    SOFA3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Q1", 
    "Q2", "Q3"), class = "factor"), LACTATES3 = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), class = "factor"), 
    SBE3 = c(5.88755625371722, -5.83367949101861, -5.16855590395164, 
    1.94584567145157, -4.46237190410756, 2.92799867956303, 6.99250801087927, 
    0.414319711015225, -16.1438604651896, 5.80900771418004, 5.08271450621078, 
    -7.1973116153256, -1.30327738092311, 4.05722685252242, -15.2431163349488, 
    -18.1380051674948, -4.84876594310452, -11.5092300657808, 
    9.46936571654563, 16.4607368929384), VBE3 = c(4.83306549999999, 
    -5.17690968000001, -3.96411408000001, 4.33224666999999, -3.45727284, 
    1.75496799999999, 7.36360999999999, 0.618853640000002, -17.29309464, 
    5.33871410999998, 6.48677951999998, -4.91616858000001, -0.740172520000016, 
    6.13709857999999, -15.35942096, -18.24841597, -3.61614233000002, 
    -12.1641, 10.34413375, 19.15572), SOF3 = c(2, 5, 6, 6, 2, 
    6, 4, 8, 14, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 11, 2, 5, 4, 4), LACT3 = c(1.9, 
    3.4, 1.4, 0.8, 1.9, 18.4, 0.5, 2.2, 10.8, 0.8, 2.4, 7.1, 
    1.9, 1.5, 1.1, 19, 3.1, 4.7, 1.1, 1), RL3 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("non", "oui"), class = "factor"), 
    OXYGENE3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("non", 
    "oui"), class = "factor"), NEW3 = c(5, 6, 8, 6, 2, 11, 6, 
    7, 6, 7, 12, 5, 10, 2, 1, 10, 5, 4, 4, 8), AGE3 = c(88, 53, 
    71, 73, 58, 71, 83, 77, 58, 77, 35, 75, 57, 64, 68, 52, 58, 
    81, 78, 77), ATB3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("non", 
    "oui"), class = "factor"), SEXE3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L), levels = c("Femme", "Homme"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")


Can you give some more information about what SBE, LACT3, SOF3 and USI3 are? Also, for picking thresholds, the ROC plots all of the thresholds that exists across all the predicted values (here predicted probabilities from your 3 logistic models). The best overall discriminative performance is model 3 (with SOFA3), but choosing a good threshold based on any model can be tough. Also, is there a reason you tested those separately? Are you trying to come away with a information about which of those 3 are "most predictive"?

This wouldn't fit in my last comment, but here's a nice resource prediction modeling strategies: https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC3575184/#S6

Hi, thanks for your response! These 3 variables are different predictors. And the variable "USI3" is the answer (yes or no). I divided these predictors into quartiles or tertiles and I created 3 models then I calculated the prediction of each model. I didn't research thresholds in advance.

Yes I am looking for the most predictive model, but I wonder if my approach is correct!!
